# Fliping 3 coin images with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to flip a coin with this 3 images, i want that each image could change when its rotating so user cant see the raw changing of each image.. i know that the solution could come with changing the percentages, but cant figure out

Conclusion: I want to "hide" when each coin changes.

This is the HTML and CSS

```css
.coin {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    animation: spin 18s ease infinite;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

    @keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/w0M0NjP/3.png");
    }

    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/w0M0NjP/3.png");
    }

    33.34% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/n7k3p0X/2.png");
    }

    66.66% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/n7k3p0X/2.png");
    }

    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/gmzSqzG/1.png");
    }
    
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/gmzSqzG/1.png");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin"></div>
```

Comment: @Johannes how that question is relevant to this one. I cannot see any relation (CSS and jQuery are 2 different worlds ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider 2 animations and it will be easier to handle. One for the rotation that will last `Xs` and the other for the image change that will last `(3/2)*Xs` with a delay of `X/4s` because you need to switch on the `90deg` angle and `90deg=360deg/4`

```css
.coin {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  animation: 
    spin 2s linear infinite,
    change 3s infinite linear .5s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes change {
  0%,33.33% {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/w0M0NjP/3.png");
  }
  33.34%,66.66% {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/n7k3p0X/2.png");
  }
  66.67%,100% {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/gmzSqzG/1.png");
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin"></div>
```

With a variable for better control

```css
.coin {
  --x:4s;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  animation: 
    spin var(--x) linear infinite,
    change calc(3*var(--x)/2) infinite linear calc(var(--x)/4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes change {
  0%,33.33% {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/w0M0NjP/3.png");
  }
  33.34%,66.66% {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/n7k3p0X/2.png");
  }
  66.67%,100% {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/gmzSqzG/1.png");
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin"></div>
```

Comment: Wow pretty cool, and what about 2 flips the same coin and then changes? Like the one that i posted

Comment: @JuanCruz you simply remove the division by 2 to keep it only 3*